# Logon Failed Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, wubi

I have a problem with my Ubuntu 13.04.

I installed it beside Windows 8 using the Wubi-installer. I installed Ubuntu on another partition of my primary hard disk as Windows 8.

When I boot in Ubuntu, I have to give a username and a password but the machine keeps saying that it is the wrong password. Even when I gave 'pppp' as a password during the installation I'm not able to logon to my Ubuntu machine.

Can somebody please help me?

Regards

Comment: wubi is dropped from 13.04 because of incompability with windows 8, how did you installed it?

Comment: @Web-E Thou *sayest* that, but my Raring image appears to have WUBI on it.  I was surprised, given that it's supposed to be dropped, but there you have it.

Comment: This is an unusual problem. I'd try resetting the password: http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password Also, please pastebin the Wubi log (`\%temp%\wubi-13.04-rev279.log`). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer, as Web-E pointed out, is that WUbI is incompatible with Windows 8, and should not have been on the CD.  The best option here is to boot from the CD (or a live USB key), and install Ubuntu directly onto its own partition.

Comment: Wubi works fine with Windows 8 - it doesn't work with computers booting with `UEFI` (so any computer that has Windows 8 preinstalled, and some Windows 7 computers).

Comment: I stand corrected.